# Testing for a function that contains asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, qunit

With qUnit, I understand how to use `asyncTest()` if you have asynchronous code within your tests, but what if you have a function that contains asynchronous code?

In other words, the asynchronous request is not within the test, but is simply part of the code that is being tested.

Take this code for example:

```
function makeAjaxCall(){
    $.get('/mypage', {}, function(data){
        // Do something with `data`
    },'json');
}
```

How can I call `makeAjaxCall()` within a test and then run tests on the `data` that is returned from the ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) in this situation. Bind it before calling, unbind it once you finish the test, possibly via the module method in Qunit.

Something like (untested):

```
asyncTest(function() {
  expect(1);

  $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) {
     var jsonRep = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
     // assert on jsonRep
     //ok(true);
  });
  $(document).ajaxError(function(e) {
     ok(false);
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
     start();

     $(document).unbind('ajaxSuccess ajaxError ajaxComplete');
  });

  makeAjaxCall();
});
```

Note that the global handlers [do not have access to the parsed contents](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7289), and you have to reparse them yourself using JSON.parse. Not ideal, but I don't know of another way.

Comment: This answer seems like it should work, but what if the asynchronous event isn't an ajax request? Would my only option be manually making an event fire from the callback?

Comment: I think so. You need to have a hook of some sort into the async process and identify that is has completed. I am not aware of any JavaScript construct to do so for every type of async operation. You can obviously create your own for well known instances like window.setTimeout by overriding the implementation and doing some magic behind the scenes, but arguably much easier to make a callback. $.Deferred can help in making the implementation clean.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nobody cares about [mockAjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax), so I found something better these days:  **[sinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/)** !
Do you know the feature autoResponse of this wonderful tool named **[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)**?
sinonJS allows you to do the same on the client side, it's a kind of ajax by-pass proxy. **if you are interested to see an example, let me know**... so sinonJS can respond to any ajax request without accessing the server, that's kind of magic if you want to mock your client, if you want to unit test your javascript code.